# LINQ - "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting this error:

"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

By using this LINQ query

I want, if A.LogOutTime is returning null then display "Unknown".

```
var listItems = (from A in data orderby A.FirstName 
    select new {
        Action = "Logout", 
        UserName = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, 
        ID = A.Id, 
        AccessDate = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown")
                       .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0], 
        AccessTimeFrame = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown")
                           .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] 
                       + " " + (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown")
                           .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2], 
        Comment = "Never delete this Archive" 
 }).Distinct();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ. Check your arrays, you are using the wrong index some where. Perhaps, trying to access an item on an empty array?

Comment: Split it out into something a bit more manageable? At a glance, you have a lot of indexes into arrays that aren't guaranteed to have that many items (e.g. if null, you set to "Unknown" which, when split, will only have a single item - an attempt to get item 1 or 2 will fail with this exception).

Comment: If you split "Unkown" on space you will get an array with only one value.

Comment: Also why is `LogOutTime` a `string` instead of a `DateTime`?

Comment: @juharr : Because I am saving LogOutTime as varchar(50) in database.

Comment: @AbhilashJA don't. That's a serious bug. Save it as `datetime`. Even if you don't want to fix that bug, *parse* the date string instead of splitting. You can retrieve the date and time part of a `DateTime` with `DateTime.Date` and `DateTime.TimeOfDay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the `A.LogOutTime` is `null` you place the string `"Unknown"` which you afterwards split by `" "` at go to some indexes of the returned `IEnumerable`. Those indexes do not exist so you get that error.

I suggest that you do something like the following:

1. Use `let` so you do not repeat the split each time. Use the C# 6.0 `?.` when splitting to avoid a `NullReferenceException` *(in the case that the `LogOutTime` is null the `sections` will also still be null)*
2. When assigning to the property check if the `LogOutTime` is `null` and if so assign the `"Unknown"`. If it isn't use the result of the split as needed
3. Use `ElementAtOrDefault(n)` so you do not access an index that does not exist

So:

```
var listItems = (from A in data 
                 orderby A.FirstName
                 let sections = A.LogOutTime?.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)            
                 select new { 
                     Action = "Logout", 
                     UserName = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, 
                     ID = A.Id, 
                     AccessDate = A.LogOutTime == null ? "Unknown" : sections.ElementAtOrDefault(0), 
                     AccessTimeFrame = A.LogOutTime == null ? "Unknown" : (sections.ElementAtOrDefault(1) + " " + 
                                       sections.ElementAtOrDefault(2)), 
                     Comment = "Never delete this Archive" }
                ).Distinct();
```

Also by checking that `LogOutTime` is not `null` I assume it is a `string`. Instead save it as a `DateTime` and then you wont have the problems of splitting and accessing some index that does not exist. Use the different properties of `DateTime` or the `ToString()` overload where you specify a desired format. For more on the matter: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "let" keyword to split the parts of the log out time only once.  Then check the length of the parts while calculating AccessTimeFrame.

```
var listItems = (from A in data
                    let logOutTimeParts = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    orderby A.FirstName
                    select new
                    {
                        Action = "Logout",
                        UserName = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName,
                        ID = A.Id,
                        AccessDate = logOutTimeParts[0],
                        AccessTimeFrame = logOutTimeParts.Length >= 3 ? logOutTimeParts[1] + " " + logOutTimeParts[2] : "",
                        Comment = "Never delete this Archive"
                    }
    ).Distinct();
```